# If two subgroups have cardinality larger than the square root of the cardinality of the group, their intersection is non-trivial.

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group G such that $\lvert H\rvert>\sqrt{\lvert G\rvert}$ and $\lvert K\rvert>\sqrt{\lvert G\rvert}$. Show that $\lvert H \cap K\rvert>1$.

Comment: And should we show it? Please demonstrate some effort on your part first.

Comment: Sir, I am trying but I couldn't understand in which way should I proceed.

Comment: You schould use mathjax  for your math expressions.  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Sir I think I have done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the set (not necessarily a group!):

$$HK := \{hk \text{ }|\text{ } h \in H, k \in K\}$$

Then recall (or note) the following fact about cardinalities from a first course on group theory:

$$|H \cap K| = \frac{|H||K|}{|HK|}$$

You are given that the numerator of the right hand side is *strictly greater than* $|G|$ since each of the factors are *strictly greater than* $\sqrt{|G|}$.

For the denominator, note that $HK$ is a subset (even if it is not a subgroup) of $G$, so $|HK|$ is *less than or equal to* $|G|$.

If the numerator is strictly greater than the denominator, then the quotient is greater than $1$.

Comment: If the fact is unfamiliar, check the wikipage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets

Answer (score -1):

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group G such that $\lvert H\rvert>\sqrt{\lvert G\rvert}$ and $\lvert K\rvert>\sqrt{\lvert G\rvert}$

$\lvert H\rvert \lvert K \rvert > \lvert G\rvert$ 
Now we know that if H and K are finite subgroups then we have 
$$ \lvert HK \rvert = \frac{ \lvert H\rvert \lvert K \rvert} { \lvert H \cap K\rvert }$$
Therefore
$$ \lvert HK \rvert > \frac{ \lvert G\rvert} { \lvert H \cap K\rvert }$$
Again 
$$ \lvert G \rvert ≥ \lvert HK\rvert $$
Hence we get result.

Comment: You have unmarked my answer as correct, and then marked your own answer - which was based on what I posted several minutes earlier - as the "correct" one. Why?

Comment: No actually at that time I didn't understand how Stack Exchange works. I tried to post one question and answer also. It is not that I did not accept your answer. I accepted your answer and also put a tick in my answer so it got unmarked from your answer. If you felt bad I am sorry.

Comment: I hope you have figured out how the site works 2.5 years later!

Comment: Not actually! I just opened it 2.5 years later. Now I will learn it and then  only I will post something.